# iOS 9 Keyboard shortcuts disable issue

Tags: objective-c, keyboard-shortcuts, ios9

I am trying to disable keyboard shortcuts and predictive text using below code.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
    textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
    [textField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
}
```

I have used return key as next button for switching textfields, below code

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
if (textField == _first) {
        [_second becomeFirstResponder];
}else if (textField == _second){
        [_third becomeFirstResponder];
}else{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
return YES;
}
```

But Keyboard flickers while switching to second textfield.after analysing i observed that UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is getting called multiple times.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs re: the return value of `textFieldShouldReturn`

> YES if the text field should implement its default behavior for the
>   return button; otherwise, NO.

Also:

> The text field calls this method whenever the user taps the return
>   button. You can use this method to implement any custom behavior when
>   the button is tapped.

So you should be returning `NO` instead of `YES` since you *do not* want the default `return` behavior being implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts,it does not work i tried with that also.i inserted return no for first and second and return yes for last button.